# Check if an image is fully loaded (without Vision Tools)

Tags: labview

I am currently developing a Labview application whose function (amongst others) is to copy and display images that are automatically updated every half a second or so. Depending on when the program copies the picture, it might not be fully generated, thus giving me an [incomplete picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QaLH.png), as opposed to when the update is finished and I obtain a [full picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p50Mb.png)

I would like to have a way to check whether the image is full or not. Using the size is not a viable option, as the amount of information and the colors on the images can vary. I don't have access to the image vision tools by the way, making my task more difficult than it should be.

Thank you for your help,

NFM

Comment: So the image you want to copy is being saved to a file? Is the same file constantly being overwritten with each new image, or is a new file created for every new image? What's the maximum acceptable delay between the image being completely written and your application displaying it?

Answer (score 1):

As a general solution, if you have access to the code for the generation of the image I would strongly suggest that you implement some additional logic that only replaces the image to be copied once it has a complete image.

Without using image processing you have to rely on some additional knowledge about the properties of image files. Once you have loaded the file into memory:
[image: Loading PNG as byte array]

You can perform any of a wide set of processing. If the image is [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) then you have a couple of options:

- Decode chunks and check for CRC Validity

  - Requires a lot of looping through but ensures 100% validity of the PNG
- Search for the 'IEND' chunk

  - Quick and easy search for a matching 4byte value that should be located near the end of the file. Not a perfect confirmation of validity if the file generation is not linear.